# Better understanding of the pre sheaf kernel

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm currently reading chapter II of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry and there defines kernel ,cokernel.....etc. everything is define on sheaf of Abelian groups.

we know that for  a sheaf morphism $\phi :\mathcal{F}-\mathcal{G}$ kernel is $\ker{\varphi}$ for sheaf of  abelian group or ring ...etc. But if $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ are sheaf of sets, then what is the equivalent condition of kernel .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the topological space $X$ you're working over, then sheaves of sets, groups, etc are just sets, groups, etc.

What is the kernel for a map of sets? I don't know of a nice notion of kernel even in this setting.

Comment: The kernel of $\phi$ is the equalizer of $\phi$ and $0$. Is that what you mean? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2):

If $C$ is an abelian category (i.e. if it has kernels, cokernels, and some additional properties), then the category of sheaves of elements of $C$ is itself an abelian category, by the constructions you mentioned. This means sheaves of abelian groups, rings, modules, etc. have well-defined kernels and cokernels. However, $\text{Set}$ is not an abelian category, and so we should not expect the category of sheaves of sets to be abelian, either.